# Hiding workflow re-assign button in Maximo

Tags: workflow, maximo

Is it possible to hide the re-assign button in the workflow dialog box for the users? and if so how?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my solution may not be the best one, but it works for me. I hid the button using CSS.

Just go to the Application Designer app and use Export system XML action from Select Action dropdown. Then pick LIBRARY XML and save it somewhere on your disk. Open it (using WordPad preferably, Notepad is causing some issues when importing back to Maximo) and CTRL+F find Complete workflow assignment dialog. Go down a bit and you'll see `<pushbutton>` with label Reassignment:

`<pushbutton id="completewf_b_4" label="Reassign" mxevent="directorinput" value="reassign"/>`

Add textcss="reassign_btn" (the name is up to you of course)

`<pushbutton id="completewf_b_4" label="Reassign" mxevent="directorinput" textcss="reassign_btn" value="reassign"/>`

Then save the file and import LIBRARY.xml back to the Maximo using Application Designer app again. Then just edit your maximo.css file (located somewhere in \applications\maximo\maximouiweb\webmodule\webclient\ depending on which skin you are using) and add:

`.reassign_btn { visibility: hidden; }`

Hope this helps :-)